# Create condition on type variants in a list

Tags: elm

So I have some type variants in a list:

```
type VariableType
    = BooleanVariable
    | ContinuousVariable
    | CategoricalVariable
    | Incorrect

mylistone = [ContinuousVariable, ContinuousVariable, ContinuousVariable]
mylisttwo = [ContinuousVariable, ContinuousVariable, CategoricalVariable]
```

I need to have a function defined as such:

```
listtype : List VariableType -> VariableType
listtype list =
    -- if (List.all isBooleanVariable list) then 
        BooleanVariable
    -- else if (List.all isContinuousVariable list) then 
        ContinuousVariable
    -- else
        CategoricalVariable
```

So the output on these two lists defined above should be:

```
listtype mylistone -- ContinuousVariable
listtype mylisttwo -- CategoricalVariable
```

But I read that it was impossible to check types after compilation type, because of type erasure. How can I define `isBooleanVariable` and `isContinuousVariable`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BooleanVariable`, `ContinuousVariable` etc. are all variants of the custom type `VariableType` and produces or represents values. So you're not actually trying to check the type of these, they all have the type `VariableType`, just their value. Which can be done with the equality operator, as with any other comparable value:

```elm
listtype : List VariableType -> VariableType
listtype list =
    if (List.all (\v -> v == BooleanVariable) list) then 
        BooleanVariable
    else if (List.all ((==) ContinuousVariable) list) then 
        ContinuousVariable
    else
        CategoricalVariable
```

Comment: Understood, another answer from SO actually confused me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535368/elm-check-the-type-of-a-value). Thank you!